# Why onLazyLoad not working for dataTable in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm getting undefined value for `selectedid` in the `fetchTest` method. Same code I'm using in a different component, but its working fine there.

```
<div class="primeng-datatable-container text-center"
    [busyIf]="primengDatatableHelper.isLoading">
    <p-dataTable #dataTable
                 (onLazyLoad)="fetchTest(testNo,$event)"
                 [value]="listTest"
                 rows="{{primengDatatableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage}}"
                 [paginator]="true"
                 [lazy]="true"
                 ScrollWidth="100%"
                 responsive="primengDatatableHelper.isResponsive"
                 resizableColumns="primengDatatableHelper.resizableColumns">
        <p-column field="testNo" header="{{l('PLUNumber')}}" [style]="{'width':'30px', 'text-align':'left'}"></p-column>
        <p-column field="flgMain" header="{{l('Main')}}" [style]="{'width':'30px', 'text-align':'left'}">
        </p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>

fetchTest(selectedid: any, event?: LazyLoadEvent): void {

}
```

**PrimeNG Version: 4.1.2**

**Angular 4**